# How to choose printer with dual extruder?

Tags: dual-nozzle

I use Prusa i3 with one extruder for some years and I would like to print from one material in two colors or from different materials for one model. Therefore I'm lookig for new printer with dual extruder.

Is there some way how to measure and/or compare quality of printers with dual extruder on the market?

For example to create 3d model - ask the seller(s) to print it - and then compare? - what details to focus on?

Comment: Without some type of budget, answers are going to be all over the place and I doubt any company selling under $1000 is going to print you a sample.

Comment: @tjb1 I agree it can be hard to make such deal with printer producer but it seems to me pretty realistic to ask one of 3D hubs as suggested by tormod-haugene below

Comment: Hi! Did you consider simply upgrading your prusa i3 to have dual extruder instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suggest yourself, ordering test prints of some model is one way to do it.

[3D Hubs](https://www.3dhubs.com) and [MakeXYZ](https://www.makexyz.com/) allows you to get your model printed by hobbyists and small businesses for a fair price. Both sites also allow you to order prints based on printer type, which I believe is what you may be looking for.

On 3D Hubs, visit on of the [trend reports](https://www.3dhubs.com/trends), and select the printer you want a sample from. Similarly, on MakeXYZ, [search local makers](https://www.makexyz.com/3dprinters/) for your desired printer.

Answer (score 3):

"Make" Magazine compares 3-D printers in a way that is as scientific as possible to help determine the strengths/weaknesses of each 3-D printer compared to others. The link to the November 2015 comparison test is available here: http://makezine.com/comparison/3dprinters/ I was unable to find the ability to compare among dual-extruders, however.